# PHP - Attach HTML to Image/Jpeg Response

Tags: php, html, mongodb

The code below:

```
if($file = $mongoGridFS->findOne(array('_id' => new MongoId($fileId)))) 
{
    $fileName = $file->file['filename'];
    $fileBytes = $file->getBytes();
    header('Content-type: image/jpeg');
    header("Content-Length: " . strlen($fileBytes));
    ob_clean();
    echo $fileBytes;
}
```

Returns the Response from Mongo as .jpg file.

How to include to this response some html? eg.

```
<div id='container'>
  <img ... /> <!-- image generated by script and stored in $fileBytes -->
  <br>
  <span class='description'>This is image</span>
</div>
```

I want not to make `<img src='...'>` linked to saved file on filesystem.

Is this possible?

Comment: Do you want to respond with a jpg or html? You can't have both. If you want html, return HTML and link to the image in question in that html.

Comment: I saw somewhere that somebody made an image from string and then he placed this image to html without linking. But I can not find that way now.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You cannot return two resources within the same http response. What you can do is to inline the image data (see [Embedding Base64 Images](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1207190/embedding-base64-images) for more details like browser compatibility and other possible issues with inline images). Something like:

```
<img src="data:image/jpeg;base64,<?=base64_encode($fileBytes)?>" />
```